# console.log(html) is not properly displaying html code for google play web app in node js scraper?

Tags: node.js, netbeans, web-scraping, cheerio

I am developing a simple web scraper for 'google play store'. I've written a program in 'node js' to get the code of an html page of 'whatsapp' in the console.

The code below is working fine for 'codedemos.com' but in case of 'play store', I cannot see the proper 'html' in the output. Why is this happening?

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('index');

// Write Headers
writeStream.write(`Title,Link,Date \n`);

//request('http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp', (error, response, html) => {
            request('http://codedemos.com/sampleblog', (error, response, html) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    console.log(html);
}
});
```

> output: codedemos.com

[image: output for: codedemos.com]

> output: play store: whatsapp page

[image: play store: whatsapp page]

[image]

Comment: This is because many modern websites are javascript rendered.
You can read about this here: https://sitebulb.com/resources/guides/how-to-crawl-javascript-websites/
. What this means is the browser itself generates the webpage using javascript when you enter the webpage. You can still scrape it with tools like Selenium.

Comment: @michael, Puppeteer is actually the preferred node tool for this rather than Selenium.

Comment: @pguardiario You are correct. I should've mentioned that Selenium is most prevalent when writing in Python.